# The name does not exist in the current context c#

Tags: c#, data-binding, charts

I'm trying to bind data with a chart to display it. However when I'm trying to link one of the columns with one of the axis of the chart it comes up with "The name Column1 does not exist in the current context" error. Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong and how to fix it?

Here is my code:

```
namespace bike
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }



    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        var col1 = new List<string>();
        var col2 = new List<string>();
        var col3 = new List<string>();
        var col4 = new List<string>();

        var Column1 = col1.Select<string, int>(q => Convert.ToInt32(q));
        var Column2 = col2.Select<string, int>(q => Convert.ToInt32(q));
        var Column3 = col3.Select<string, int>(q => Convert.ToInt32(q));
        var Column4 = col4.Select<string, int>(q => Convert.ToInt32(q));



        dataGridView1.Columns.Add("col1", "Heart Rate");
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add("col2", "Speed");
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add("col3", "Power");
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add("col4", "Altitude");




        DialogResult result = openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
        if (result == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(openFileDialog1.FileName))
            {

                int row = 0;
                string line;

                bool isInHRData = false;

                while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) !=null)
                {
                    if (!isInHRData)
                    {
                        if (line != "[HRData]")
                            continue;
                        isInHRData = true;
                        continue;
                    }

                    else if (line.StartsWith("[") && line.EndsWith("["))
                        break;

                    string[] columns = line.Split('\t');
                    if (columns.Length > 0)
                        col1.Add(columns[0]);
                    if (columns.Length > 1)
                        col2.Add(columns[1]);
                    if (columns.Length > 2)
                        col3.Add(columns[2]);
                    if (columns.Length > 3)
                        col4.Add(columns[3]);        

                    /*col1.Add(columns[0]);
                    col2.Add(columns[1]);
                    col3.Add(columns[2]);
                    col4.Add(columns[3]);
                     */

                    dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
                    for (int i = 0; i < columns.Length; i++)
                    {
                        dataGridView1[i, row].Value = columns[i];
                    }
                    row++; 
                }

                int maxSpeed = Column2.Max();
                maxSpeed = maxSpeed / 10;
                string MaxSpeed = Convert.ToString(maxSpeed);
                textBox1.Text = MaxSpeed;

                double aveSpeed = Column2.Average();
                aveSpeed = aveSpeed / 10;
                aveSpeed = Math.Round(aveSpeed, 0);
                string AveSpeed = Convert.ToString(aveSpeed);
                textBox2.Text = AveSpeed;

                double aveHeart = Column1.Average();
                aveHeart = Math.Round(aveHeart, 0);
                string AveHeart = Convert.ToString(aveHeart);
                textBox3.Text = AveHeart;

                int maxHeart = Column1.Max();
                string MaxHeart = Convert.ToString(maxHeart);
                textBox4.Text = MaxHeart;

                int minHeart = Column1.Min();
                string MinHeart = Convert.ToString(minHeart);
                textBox5.Text = MinHeart;

                double avePower = Column3.Average();
                avePower = Math.Round(avePower, 0);
                string AvePower = Convert.ToString(avePower);
                textBox6.Text = AvePower;

                int maxPower = Column3.Max();
                string MaxPower = Convert.ToString(maxPower);
                textBox7.Text = MaxPower;

                double aveAltitude = Column4.Average();
                aveAltitude = Math.Round(aveAltitude, 0);
                string AveAltitude = Convert.ToString(aveAltitude);
                textBox8.Text = AveAltitude;

                int maxAltitude = Column4.Max();
                string MaxAltitude = Convert.ToString(maxAltitude);
                textBox9.Text = MaxAltitude;

            }
        }

    }


    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        chart1.DataSource = dataGridView1;
        chart1.Series["Series1"].XValueMember = Column1;
        chart1.Series["Series1"].YValueMembers = "test";
        chart1.DataBind();
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

You're declaring `Column1` as a *local variable* within your (rather long) `button1_Click` method. If you want it to be part of the state of the object, which will make it available in `button2_Click`, you should declare it as an *instance variable* instead.

You might want to consider what will happen if button 2 is clicked before button 1 though.

Comment: so you mean declare Column1 outside button1_Click inside public_Form1?

Comment: I guess i can catch the exception if the button2 is clicked first, is that correct?

Comment: @user2047427: No, inside `class Form1`. There's no such thing as `public_Form1`. Declare it as a field, not a local. And don't catch an exception - you could just check whether the value is null. Or you could only enable button 2 when button 1 is clicked and the field is set appropriately.

Comment: Right, so I put string Column1 under class Form1. Thing is what do I do with the "var Column1 = col1.Select<string, int>(q => Convert.ToInt32(q));" under button1_Click?

Comment: @user2047427: You need to just turn that into an assigmment. How new are you to C#? I ask because I get the feeling you're fairly new, in which case you'd be better off learning from the basics, without using LINQ and GUIs.

Comment: I am very new to it. The requirement is to make it in forms tho. I have no idea how to turn it to assignment. I've tried 'string Column1 = null;' and then convert the line under button1_Click to 'Column1 = col1.Select<string, int>(q => Convert.ToInt32(q));' but that does not work

Comment: @user2047427: There's no point in continuing to try to fix up something complicated when you're out of your depth. I *strongly* recommend that you get hold of a good beginner's guide to C#, and read that carefully so you understand the basics of the language before you go back to this task.

Comment: @user2047427: Well I certainly don't have time to help you fix your code one line at a time because you didn't take the time to learn the language properly, I'm afraid. This site is about helping people to become better developers - it's not a just shortcut for getting through an assignment.